# What is the difference between microscopic quantum interference between photons and macroscopic interference between laser beams?

Tags: waves, quantum-entanglement, interference, interferometry

To get interference between laser beams we use an interferometer composed of mirrors and one beam splitter.

To get interference between photons we use an interferometer composed of polarizers, dichroic mirrors, wave plates, phase shifters, prisms and a beam splitter and even then, we only get interference with less than 100% chance

Why is interference between individual photons so hard and why do we have to include so many lenses? What is the difference between macroscopic interference and quantum interference?

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by *microscopic quantum interference*?   How does it differ from *interference*?

Comment: It differs through the way it is created. That Anton Zeilinger uses many lenses to generate it: wave plates, filters, polarizers, dichroic mirror, prisms and it is also called HONG OU MANDEL EFFECT. For macro interference they use mirrors and beamsplitter and lasers, not many lenses. It makes no sense though, because it also says on Wikipedia everything you need is two indistingushable photons and a beamsplitter, what is the role of the other lenses in the experiment ?